# can't test default role with rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tdd, rspec2

I'm truing to test whether user have default role of 'user' after creation. For roles, i have cancan and devise on authentication.

In my user model I have this snipped

```
after_create :default_role

private
    def default_role
       self.roles << Role.find_by_name("user")
       self.save
    end
```

in user.spec.rb this

```
it 'should have default role' do
  role = Role.create! name: 'user'
  user = User.create!(name: 'Andrew', email: "asdf@asds.sd", password: "12341234", password_confirmation: '12341234')
  user.roles.count.should > 0
```

end

and rspec output

```
Failure/Error: user.roles.count.should > 0
   expected: > 0
        got:   0
```

So I trued to debug this through console using

```
user = User.create! name: 'Andrew', email: "asdf@asds.sd", password: "12341234", password_confirmation: '12341234'
```

after success creation of new user instance I run

```
user.has_role? :user
```

and it returned true...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Rspec after creating User. You have to reload "user object" as soon as creating it. Rewrite your code like the following

```
it 'should have default role' do
  role = Role.create! name: 'user'
  user = User.create!(name: 'Andrew', email: "asdf@asds.sd", password: "12341234", password_confirmation: '12341234')
  user.reload
  user.roles.count.should > 0
end
```